# Jupyter server Error 500: Internal Server Error when opening Matlab notebook

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Hi I am getting this weird error whenever I try to open a Matlab Notebook on jupyter lab, which does not happen when I am opening a python notebook. Here is the error from the terminal:

```
 [W 2022-10-12 14:32:49.160 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:32:49.829 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:32:50.152 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[I 2022-10-12 14:34:27.806 LabApp] Build is up to date
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.043 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.058 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.261 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.270 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.295 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.309 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.374 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.391 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.501 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.513 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.538 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.548 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.625 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.637 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.684 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.692 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.715 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.727 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.888 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:28.896 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[E 2022-10-12 14:34:29.398 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /matlab/ (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/matlab/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_proxy\websocket.py", line 91, in get
        return await self.http_get(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_proxy\handlers.py", line 683, in http_get
        return await ensure_async(self.proxy(self.port, path))
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\utils.py", line 189, in ensure_async
        result = await obj
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_proxy\handlers.py", line 677, in proxy
        await self.ensure_process()
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_proxy\handlers.py", line 654, in ensure_process
        await proc.start()
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpervisor\process.py", line 103, in start
        atexitasync.add_handler(self._handle_signal)
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpervisor\atexitasync.py", line 18, in add_handler
        loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, _handle_signal, signal.SIGINT)
      File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 539, in add_signal_handler
        raise NotImplementedError
    NotImplementedError
[E 2022-10-12 14:34:29.401 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \"Opera GX\";v=\"90\"",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.117",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|f2807385|12e0336e05c04f8ecc1e372d38057c27|1663853285; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1665581153|23:username-localhost-8889|44:MWRmMGE3ODM5MWRlNDA5MmEyOGMzNTNiNTcwZjJjODY=|fcc33aa342369d6fce3dcc183d38de560e31a1ffd79c79583a466f0b7448f0a5\"; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1665581669|23:username-localhost-8888|44:OWQ0Y2I3NGFlYTNkNGFmMWIzZjg3OTlkNmQ5ZThkZGM=|83814eac8eb4befb0ffe587f1700d01ce3412b50b7588b73d19cabb7dacd5f74\""
    }
[E 2022-10-12 14:34:29.401 ServerApp] 500 GET /matlab/ (::1) 6.50ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:29.585 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:29.595 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:29.775 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:29.785 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:29.995 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.212 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.269 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.328 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.443 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.503 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.611 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.669 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\Scripts\matlab-proxy-app.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matlab_proxy\app.py", line 675, in main
    app = configure_and_start(app)
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matlab_proxy\app.py", line 593, in configure_and_start
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_runner.py", line 121, in start
    self._server = await loop.create_server(
  File "C:\Users\prrpe\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1506, in create_server
    raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 59017): only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.724 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:30.942 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:31.856 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-10-12 14:34:32.061 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
```

I have tried the solutions in other Error 500 tickets, but none have worked, I assume it has something to do with the Matlab template, any idea how I may be able to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The windows support for `jupyter-matlab-proxy` is gated on an issue with `jupyter-server-proxy` which is a package it depends on.
More information on the issue can be viewed in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy/pull/181).

From the looks of it, the PR has a suggested workaround to additionally install [jupyter-server-proxy-windows](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-server-proxy-windows/) to work around the issue.

I haven't personally tested this workaround and cannot speak to its efficacy.
Please update this thread with any information if you attempt the suggested workaround.